# NTFS appears every time

Tags: macos, mac, startup, settings, ntfs

Every time I boot my Mac, an "NTFS for Mac OS X" window appears.
In the settings I can't change this.
Here is the window
[image]

I have El capitan 10.11.4

I found this:

> To resolve the issue you need to delete the service which is starting Preferences Panel with NTFS for Mac OS X.
>
> 1. Go to Applications - Utilities
> 2. Open Terminal
> 3. Type in
>
> sudo rm /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.paragon.NTFS.notify.plist
>
> 4. Press Enter and provide Administrator password
> 5. Press Enter again
>
> Preferences pane will not pop up again.

But the file *com.paragon.NTFS.notify.plist* does not exist.

Any solution?

PS: sorry for my english, im from Argentina

PPS: It does not appear as part of the Login Items

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot, your system version and any additional useful information to your question by editing it!

Comment: When exactly during the boot process does the window/message appear (before or after user login)? Do you have any third party NTFS driver installed?

Comment: @patrix after user login. I do not install anything else. When i said "a window appears" i mean the program itself

Comment: You (or somebody else) at least installed Paragon NTFS (which is.a 3rd party app). Do you need to access any NTFS formatted drives?

Comment: @patrix sorry i didnt know what 3rd party means. Yes i want to keep the app if it is what you mean. I use an external hard drive in NTFS format

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Go to System Settings -> Users and Groups
2. CLick the Login Items tab.
3. If the program is listed here, you should be able to hide it when logging in by check the box next to the program item or if you don't want it to open automatically (in case you don't need to access NTFS formatted drives) you can highlight the item and click the minus in the bottom og the window right under the list of items.

Comment: Paragon NTFS does not appear in the list

Comment: @AgustinLuques Do "System Preferences" appear in the list?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://osxuninstaller.com/uninstall-guides/remove-paragon-ntfs-for-mac/), there are several steps. Importantly, there is an “uninstall” button in the system preferences pane, and then you need to remove the preference pane itself, and clean up any files left on the hard disk.

Comment: While there's nothing especially wrong on that page, this appears to be one of those spammy websites with a product to sell that basically shows you the same generic instructions for any application you search for.

Comment: Towards the bottom there is some stuff that looks relevant, though. I went straight past the stuff about “go to Applications and drag the application to the Trash”, to the stuff that actually looked application-specific

Answer (score 0):

Check in `/System/Library/LaunchDeamons/` for files starting with `com.paragon-software` and delete all of them.

In my case there were three files:

```
com.paragon-software.ntfsd.plist
com.paragon-software.ntfs.loader.plist
com.paragon-software.installer.plist
```